# Why does emacs not apply some config settings when editing tex files?

Tags: auctex, text-editing

I'm facing a rather peculiar situation where my emacs settings seem to be lost every time that I open a `.tex` file. That's doesn't happen when I'm editing `.el` or `.py` files. Heres some examples with normal setting editing `.el` file

[image]

And here when I try to edit `.tex` file
[image]

Any ideas what have gone wrong here?

Thanks! 
Original post posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/db9ifg/why_emacs_loses_its_editor_config_when_editting/) initially.

Comment: Please clarify what you expect to see when you open a tex file.

Comment: Please what is your Emacs version? Also, is there any `.tex` related settings in your Emacs config? When did you notice this behavior? Since always or after updating some part of your Emacs config?

Comment: Please don't double-post here and Reddit.

Comment: @Dan I expect to see my line numbers and column indicator as configured in the first instance.

Comment: @Nsukami_ NU Emacs 26.3 of 2019-08-31

Comment: @mankoff sorry about that I've edited the original post to reflect that

Comment: @mankoff: Why is there a problem double-posting here and Reddit? I wouldn't encourage doing that for no reason, but the two sites have different purposes, and a similar question can get different feedback/help. (We do discourage posting both here and StackOverflow, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my problem was a comment from `The_Blackbeard` user at reddit. 
`Have you taken into account that while emacs-lisp-mode derives from prog-mode, tex-mode derives from text-mode?`

Once I had that information the rest was easy to fix.

The solution was to add a hook:
`(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(fci-mode linum-mode))`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you did to fix the problem for future readers?

Comment: @Dan I updated the answer to reflect the necessary changes in order to get back line numbers and column indicator for tex files. Let me know if that helps?

Comment: Thank you!  That helps the next person who has a similar problem.

Comment: Please also accept your answer as soon as the system allows you. Self-answers are encouraged.